# Scraping website (marketchameleon) returns encrypted data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am learning how to scrape websites with python, for now just been using requests and BeautifulSoup...

I am trying to access the following page: https://marketchameleon.com/Overview/BAX/Earnings/Earnings-Dates

Yes, you need a subscription to see all data, but it is just for learning purposes so the few data that is visible in the browser should be enough.

Heres how I get the data:

```
import requests
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers_Get = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1'
}
url = 'https://marketchameleon.com/Overview/BAX/Earnings/Earnings-Dates'
response = requests.get(url, headers_Get)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, “html.parser”)
```

However, the html data returned seems to be encrypted (just an extract as the encrypted part is quite long):

```
<div class="symov_earnings">
<div class="flex_container_between flex_center_vertical">
<div class="dl-tbl-outer"><div class="dis-prem"><button class="_noprem prem-btn" onclick="site_OpenPremium();">Download Now</button><div class="dis-prem-pop"><p>Premium Feature</p><p><a href="/Account/Login">Login</a><span>|</span><a href="/Subscription/Compare">Subscribe</a></p></div></div></div>
</div>
<div cipherxx="OwA+ADwAOQA+ADwABABEAFcAVgBdAFYAEwBfAFwADQAUAEcASABeAGwAUABNAEQAaQBRAFAAQQBdAF8AVgBXAEUAFgARAFAAXwBXAEsAQwALABYAXABDAGwAWgBRAFcAXgBAAFMAXABBAFIAXQBCABQACgA8ADkAEwAWABgAEAAKAEAAWQBWAFIAUgAGAD0APAAUABEAEwATABYAGAAQABYACABFAEEAEwBVAFQAUQBFAEcADAARAF4AVwBRAF4AaQBcAFQAUgBXAF8AVgBXABQACgA8ADkAEwAWABgAEAAWABQAEQATABMAFgAYABAACgBAAFkAEwBQAFkAVABDAEYAVQBfAA4AEQAOABoADgBjAEQAUgBcAF4AXwBWAFcAFgBxAFAAQQBdAF8AVgBXAEUACAAeAEcAWwAIADUAOgAWABQAEQATABMAFgAYABAACgAbAEUAQQANA
```

Is there any way to find out what is happening (how the site is protected from scrapers?) and to get the actual html data?

Thanks

Comment: You may be blocked , I have tried your code . you can the check staus code print(response.status_code)

Comment: @m-zayan be informed that's not considered as type of `block`, the site is running `JavaScript` code dynamically once the page loads, therefor, the `cipherxx` is a sort of `div` which hold a `value` for `HTML` decoder

Comment: Thanks Mr  @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη, Everything works well when I run the same code . I am running same code from different server.That's why I guessed he might be blocked.

Comment: @m-zayan that's could be due to the region or the back-end `dns` used for the `request` itself. you can validate that by `curl` or `r.status_code`

Answer (score 2):

The data are indeed encrypted. If you look at the JS files that are part of the website you can spot [this particular file](https://marketchameleon.com/bundles/MCJSFull3?v=1bxMt1eDNW5b9Wc5L35gXbq5k_2bqU1C58o6kr-C2Fk1) which contain the function used to decrypt the data. All this is done in Javascript so you have 2 options here :

- use [beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup) to **scrape** the page, recode the javascript decryption function in python
- use a headless browser like [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium)

Using the first option (recoding the encryption function in [python](/questions/tagged/python)), here is how you could do that :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import base64
import json

url = "https://marketchameleon.com/Overview/BAX/Earnings/Earnings-Dates"

session = requests.Session()

r = session.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

key = session.cookies.get_dict()["v1"]
encryptedDivs = [ i["cipherxx"] for i in soup.find_all("div") if i.get("cipherxx")]

unencrypted = []
for div in encryptedDivs:
    encryptedData = base64.b64decode(div)
    cipher = "".join([
        chr(encryptedData[i]) 
        for i in range(0,len(encryptedData),2)
    ])
    data = ""
    for i in range(0, len(cipher)):
        c_num = ord(cipher[i])
        k_num = ord(key[i % len(key)])
        c2 = c_num ^ k_num
        data += chr(c2)

    unencrypted.append(data)

# unencrypted[0] is the header div with some info about stock price etc...
# unencrypted[1] is the first table
# lets parse the second table unencrypted[2]

soup = BeautifulSoup(unencrypted[2], "html.parser")

tbody = soup.find("tbody").findAll("tr", recursive=False)
thead = soup.find("thead").findAll("tr", recursive=False)

table2 = [
    {
        "Date": t[0].text.strip(),
        "Time": t[1].text.strip(),
        "Period": t[2].text.strip(),
        "Conference Call": t[3].text.strip(),
        "Price Effect" : t[4].find("span").text if t[4].find("span") else t[4].text.strip(),
        "Implied Straddle": t[5].text.strip(),
        "Closing Price": t[6].text.strip(),
        "Opening Gap": t[7].text.strip(),
        "Drift Since": t[8].text.strip(),
        "Range Since": t[9].text.strip(),
        "Price Change 1 Week Before":t[10].text.strip(),
        "Price Change 1 Week After": t[11].text.strip()
    }
    for t in (t.findAll('td', recursive=False) for t in tbody)
    if len(t) >= 11
]

print(json.dumps(table2, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

Note that the encryption key is located in the cookie named `v1` (which is why you need `requests.Session()`)

#### Encryption part

This is [XOR encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher). It XOR the value of the data with a key (in this case the key is stored in a cookie). For the decryption, you just need to XOR the cipher with the key to get the original data back.

The most efficient way to explain it is to use an example :

- data is the string "HELLO"
- key is the string "97523022"

```markdown
"H"       "E"        "L"        "L"        "O"
 72        69         76         76         79
 01001000  01000101   01001100   01001100   01001111


"9"       "7"        "5"        "2"        "3"
 57        55         53         50         51
 00111001  00110111   00110101   00110010   00110011
 
     01001000  01000101   01001100   01001100   01001111
XOR  00111001  00110111   00110101   00110010   00110011
==>  01110001  01110010   01111001   01111110   01111100         
       113        114       121        126        124
HEX   \x71       \x72      \x79       \x7E       \x7C


complete with 0s  :
HEX    \x71\x00 \x72\x00 \x79\x00 \x7E\x00 \x7C\x00

encode \x71\x00\x72\x00\x79\x00\x7E\x00\x7C\x00 to base64

which gives : 'cQByAHkAfgB8AA=='
```

try this code to decrypt (same code as the code at the beginning of the question) :

```
key = "97523022"
payload = "cQByAHkAfgB8AA=="

data = base64.b64decode(payload)

cipher = "".join([
    chr(data[i]) 
    for i in range(0,len(data),2)
])
data = ""
for i in range(0, len(cipher)):
    c_num = ord(cipher[i])
    k_num = ord(key[i % len(key)])
    c2 = c_num ^ k_num
    data += chr(c2)

print(data)
```

Output :

> HELLO

You can also check [this link](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/19471/36766) and [this wiki](https://teambi0s.gitlab.io/bi0s-wiki/crypto/xor/) if your are interested

Comment: if you don't mind, could you please explain the two blocks of `cipher` and `data` ?

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη I've added some explanation about xor encryption

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get(
    "https://marketchameleon.com/Overview/BAX/Earnings/Earnings-Dates")


soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

print(soup.prettify())
```

> You don't need to pass headers with that particular website. as the the website is responding with `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` which doesn't need to pass a kind of `headers`.

You can check the `curl` response to make sure that you are on the right track:

```
curl -D - https://marketchameleon.com/Overview/BAX/Earnings/Earnings-Dates
```